# Как составить регулярное выражение js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте, помогите составить регулярку.
Есть строка, если в строке например есть 453|571 то взять все что до " " (пробела)

```
var str = '461|572|0|4|29|29|7809169 453|571|0|2|66|66|7809053 446|565|0|4|41|41|7809052';
if(str.indexOf('453|571')>=0){
var res = str.match('регулярочка');
console.log('453|571|0|2|66|66|7809053');
}
```

Comment: `(^| )([^ ]*453[|]571[^ ]*)($| )`

Comment: @Akina спасибо!)

Answer (score 3):

А что мешает использовать split?

```js
var str = '461|572|0|4|29|29|7809169 453|571|0|2|66|66|7809053 446|565|0|4|41|41|7809052';
if(str.indexOf('453|571')>=0){
var res = str.split(' ');
console.log(res[1]);
}
```

Comment: А если "453|571" будет не после первого пробела?

Comment: у меня не много опыта в js. Но мне кажется что через split будет более прожорливо. т.к. нужно будет перебирать все значения массива? в документации нашел только $.isArray но она возвращает только индекс, а мне нужено значение